# jQuery Beginner - Explain logic of this if statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have recently been going through a jQuery Tutorial and the guy breezed over something that I didn't really understand... The script and markup is:

```js
  $("document").ready(function() {
      $("#example p").replaceWith(replacementFn);
  });

  function replacementFn() {
      if ($(this).text().indexOf("1") != -1) {
          return "<p>This is paragraph uno</p>";
      }
      else {
          return this.outerHTML;
      }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="example">
    <p class="a">This is paragraph 1</p>
    <p id="para1">This is paragraph 2</p>
    <p class="b">This is paragraph 3</p>
    <p id="para4" lang="en-us">This is paragraph 4</p>
    <p id="para5" lang="en-gb">This is paragraph 5</p>
</div>
```

The thing that I don't understand here is the logic behind 'if ($(this).text().indexOf("1") != -1'.  I understand that != means 'not equal to' and that we're looking in each p element for a number '1' but I guess I don't understand what -1 means here and why it makes the statement true.

The guy in the tutorial simply says 'Let's look for the string "one", and that's not equal to one, that means it was found' and then moves on.

I'm sure this is very obvious to programmers but I'm more of a front-end developer trying to get some basics of jQuery and Javascript. Any explanation that would make sense to a relative layman would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The `.indexOf()` function returns `-1` when it does not find the search target in the string.

Comment: Any non-negative number returned from `.indexOf()` is the index which was found.  `-1` means no index was found, because `-1` is always outside of the index range.  (Technically all negative numbers are always outside of the index range, but `-1` is used by convention.)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf

Comment: The thing is, you don't need to be a programmer to search the internet. "jquery text()" gets you what that function does. "javascript indexOf" gets you the link @j08691 provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `$(this).text().indexOf("1")`-

1. In `$(this)`, `$` is jQuery Object and `this` is reference of current Node in the function and is being passed as selector to jQuery Object.,
2. `.text()` jQuery function selects text (not html) from the HTML Node (point 1)
3. `.indexOf("1")` JavaScript core function finds the position of "1" *(call it substring, don't confused with index 1)* in the selected text (point 2) [1 is present in the first paragraph] (If `indexOf("Find_What")` does not finds what we asked, it returns `-1`.

> Basically `indexOf` returns index of the match in the string and it
> may be 0, 1 so on if match is present else `-1` if match is not
> present.

For example-

`"1st paragraph".indexOf("1");`

IndexOf("1") will return 0 as it is at first position.

`"<p>paragraph 1</p>".indexOf("1")`
In this case it will return 13.

So `-1` is sure case for the absence of "1" (match) in the string.

*PS- Also indexOf is faster and preferred function to search something in a string in JavaScript.*

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) you can quench your thirst for more knowledge of 'indexOf'.

Comment: Ok Thanks (and to other responses) that clears it up for me. I understood the jquery selector etc. the thing I was missing is that indexOf() returns -1 if it's not found, making the statement say 'if index of 1 is not equal to 'not found' which makes sense! Cheers everyone.

Comment: @Barry indexOf is prefered and beloved method among developers. :)

Answer (score 2):

The indexOf() function returns the position in the string where the substring being searched for first occurs, and returns -1 if the substring does not occur.

In this example, `text().indexOf("1")` returns the position where 1 first appears.  If `1` doesn't exist, then indexOf() returns -1.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($(this).text().indexOf("1") != -1)
```

JavaScript's `indexOf()` returns `-1` if the string provided as the argument is NOT contained in the string that is searched, and otherwise the position of the search string inside the searched string.

Like most languages, JavaScript uses zero-based indexes, so a return value of `0` would mean that "1" occurs at the very beginning of the searched string.

Answer (score 0):

the function `replacementFn` will check if `$(this).text()` (called element text) contains "1" `.indexOf("1")` and if it does it will return `"<p>This is paragraph uno</p>"`

when `indexOf()` value equals `-1` this means it didn't find a match so we want it to not be equals to `-1` aka `!= -1`

the returned string then will be used by jQuery's [.replaceWith()](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) to replace the text of the matched element.

Answer (score 0):

indexOf returns the location at which "1" is present.
indexOf("1") would return 18 in 'T0','h1','i2','s3',' 4','i5','s6',' 7','p8','a9','r10','a11','g12','r13','a14','p15','h16',' 17','118'
whereas it will return -1 for other strings as 1 is not present in these strings

Comment: What do you mean by `return 18`? You answer doesn't match what we expect. Someone may return `-1` to you. :D

Answer (score 0):

Let's work through this snippet as a whole, so you can get a better understanding of it.

You can see that there's a `$(document).ready()` call - this checks if the whole page has been loaded and if so, executes the function passed as an argument.

That function consist of searching for DOM nodes (you can understand them as HTML elements for now, but it's a bit more complex) that can be described by the `#example p` selector - basically, this means that the `$('#example p')` call will return all `<p>` elements that are contained in an element with an id of `example`.

Later, there's a chained method call - [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/), that takes a function as a parameter. What this chained method call does is replace the content of the elements it's called on with what's passed to it as an argument. In this case, it's what our parameter function returns.

The `replacementFn` function searches through the content ([`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/)) of the aforementioned DOM nodes passed as `$(this)` with the [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method, which searches the string it's called on for a character sequence passed as a parameter to it and returns `-1` if the sequence isn't found or an integer greater than `-1`, but not greater than the length of the string it's called on, if the sequence is found - in this case, the returned number is the index of the string, from which the sought-for sequence starts.

Back to the `replacementFn` - it searches the text content of the DOM nodes it's passed and if it contains the character `1` (ergo the value returned by `.indexOf()` is greater than `-1`), it changes the content of the node to `<p>This is paragraph uno</p>`.

If the node doesn't contain the `1` character (i.e. the `.indexOf()` method returned `-1`), it leaves the node as it is by returning its current content, so that the `.replaceWith()` method doesn't do anything.

I hope that you get it now - if something is not clear to you, let me know via a comment.

Related links:

http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/

http://api.jquery.com/text/

https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf/

Comment: The answer should be specific.